# Push Notification works Firefox but not work Chrome: Required member title is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, push

I have a service worker running for push notifications. It register well but when i send a push notification works in firefox but not work in chrome (Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)). Chrome worker recibe the push but can create the notification object.

Chrome Error "worker.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'showNotification' on 'ServiceWorkerRegistration': required member title is undefined.
    at worker.js:6"

```
self.addEventListener('push', ev => {
  const data = ev.data.json();
  self.registration.showNotification('Harcoded title', {
    actions: [{action: "get"}],
    body: data.body,
    title: 'Another hardcoded for testing',
    vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
    tag: 'SPI',
    icon: '/spi40/images/logo_spi.jpg'
  }).then(function(NotificationEvent) {console.log(NotificationEvent) });
  self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow('http://192.168.2.106/spi40/')
    );
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that firefox not implement Action yet. 
Chrome implement and expect  actions: [{action: "get",title:"titlehere"}]
So, the problem is not the notification title, is the action title.

Comment: Thanks, I've struggled for hours. It's "action" that works on Chrome not "actions", despite what the [docs says here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) at the time of writing.